# Programming Spam Prevention

Tags: php, spam-prevention, spam

What is the most secure way to fight spam? Any algorithm?O r way to fight back spammers?

Comment: Shoot the bastards. But a more practical answer is impossible without knowing a bit more about the problem - do you mean in user-submitted content? Incoming email? Something else? How do your current spam problems manifest? How do you authenticate currently?

Answer (score 8):

Get a captcha dude, it's probably the best way to defeat spam. Here is a great one called [reCaptcha](http://recaptcha.net/). It's pretty easy to integrate with PHP and is mighty effective. [Here is how you do it.](http://recaptcha.net/plugins/php/)

Answer (score 1):

[Mollom](http://mollom.com/) is a more user-friendly alternative to reCaptcha. It can be set to only require CAPTCHA validation if the content of the submission looks "spammy", so it doesn't interfere with users entering safe submissions.

Answer (score 1):

3 simple methods that I use on my employer's website contact form that really help out:

1. Set a serverside timestamp when the contact page loads, and check the
   time again when it posts. If your form was submitted in under 5 seconds (or
   whatever minimal time is reasonable for your form) then you know its a bot since
   humans aren't that fast.
2. Check for multiple tag types in the message. Much of spam we see spam tries to mix html and
   bulletin board style tags, so you get `<a>` and `[url=] [link=]` in the
   same message, this is an easy to check red flag
3. Create a hidden text input field called email and name the visible
   email field something different. Human visitors won't see that field, so if it has a
   value its a bot(technically could be a
   blind person with a screen reader but highly unlikely)

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong, but I don't think Auto Fill would work then. Because it would be putting your email in the email field therefore automatically marking your submission as spam.

Comment: Thats a totally plausable scenario, especially since different autofill plugins would vary in how they were programmed, but in over 5 years of using these techniques Ive never had a false positive on a legitimate contact submission for this reason. Very seldomly I'll see false a positives for people with weird browser settings that wont keep the session so the timestamp comparison fails.